# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream

Tags: java, spring-boot, nio, spring-rest

I tested via Postman the application and get this warning:

> "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream"

maybe someone knows how to resolve this problem?

code is presented below

My Controller

```
@RestController
public class FileServiceController {

private FileService fileService;

@Autowired
public FileServiceController(FileService fileService) {
    this.fileService = fileService;
}

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/write")
public ResponseEntity writeToFile(@RequestParam final String sessionId,  @RequestParam final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    return path != null ? new ResponseEntity<>(fileService.openForWriting(sessionId, path),
            HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/files")
public ResponseEntity getFiles( @RequestParam final String sessionId, @RequestParam final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    return path != null ? new ResponseEntity<>(fileService.getFiles(sessionId, path), HttpStatus.FOUND) :
            new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/read")
public ResponseEntity readFromFile(@RequestParam final String sessionId, @RequestParam final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    return path != null ? new ResponseEntity<>(fileService.openForReading(sessionId, path), HttpStatus.FOUND) :
            new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/delete")
public ResponseEntity deleteFromFile(@RequestParam final String sessionId, @RequestParam final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    return path != null ? new ResponseEntity<>(fileService.delete(sessionId, path), HttpStatus.OK) :
            new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

}
```

My FileServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

@Override
public OutputStream openForWriting(final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    try {
        return Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(path), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new FileServiceException("cannot open entry", e);
    }
}

@Override
public InputStream openForReading(final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    try {
        return Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(path));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new FileServiceException("cannot open entry", e);
    }
}

@Override
public List<String> getFiles(final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))) {
        return paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(Path::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FileServiceException("cannot get files", e);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean delete(final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException {
    Path rootPath = Paths.get(path);
    try {
        Files.walk(rootPath)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .forEach(File::delete);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FileServiceException("cannot delete entries", e);
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface FileService {

@NotNull OutputStream openForWriting(@NotNull final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException;

@NotNull InputStream openForReading(@NotNull final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException;

@NotNull List<String> getFiles(@NotNull final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException;

boolean delete(@NotNull final String sessionId, final String path) throws FileServiceException;
```

}

App

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FileServiceApplication {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FileServiceApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Comment: What did you run !?

Answer (score 0):

`FileServiceImpl.openForReading()` returns an `InputStream` and this is what you put in your response in `FileServiceController.readFromFile()`. The `InputStream` is not serializable, hence the exception.

Instead of an `InputStream`, you should put the content you read from it, e.g a `byte[]`, a string or whatever object your application deals with.